# C: Multi process CMD does nothing after running all commands

Tags: c, cmd, concurrency

I made this in C, and it does run all commands concurrently. But at the end, it puts the last command in the user input part of the CMD then does nothing right after. 
This is the output of the command:

```
hen03:~/Lab_08> ./assign8 whoami , ls -a , pwd
Child Process: PID=11895, PPID=11894, Command=whoami
Child Process: PID=11897, PPID=11894, Command=pwd
Child Process: PID=11896, PPID=11894, Command=ls
/home/uid454/Lab_08
hen03:~/Lab_08> .  ..  assign8  assign8.c  makefile  uid454.zip
uid454

hen03:~/Lab_08>
```

And this is the code I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

void startProcesses(int commands, char *commandList[6][100]){
    static pid_t forks[6];
    int status[6];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < commands; i++){
      switch(forks[i] = fork()){
            case -1: //failed
            perror("fork failed");
                break;
            case 0: //child does things 
                printf("Child Process: PID=%ld, PPID=%ld, Command=%s\n", (long) getpid(), (long) getppid(), commandList[i][0]);
                if(execvp(commandList[i][0], commandList[i]) < 0){
                    printf("something failed\n");
                }
                break;
            default:
                if(i == commands-1){
                    waitpid(forks[i], &status[i], 0);
                }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int commandNum = 0, index, numOfCommands = 1, j =0;
    static char *commandList[6][100];

    //start of separate algo
    for (index = 1; index < argc; index++){
        if(strcmp(strtok(argv[index], " "), ",") == 0){
            commandNum++;
            numOfCommands++; 
            commandList[commandNum-1][j] = NULL;
            j = 0;
            continue;
        }
        else{
            commandList[commandNum][j] = argv[index];
            j++;
        }

    }
    //end of separation algo

    startProcesses(numOfCommands, commandList);
    return 0;
}
```

I honestly have no idea what the problem is nor how to even google it for that matter. Could someone explain why its doing this?

edit: took out line numbers

Comment: Please don't include line-numbers in your examples, it makes it much harder for us to try it out ourselves. If there's a specific line you want to draw our attention to, then add a comment to it and mention it in the question body.

Comment: What will happen if you put `ls -a` as a first command? I suspect that your parsing is wonky

Comment: it ran perfectly... still not sure why though

Comment: Well, I expected the opposite :) Then it is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the problem that the output of some child-processes are shown tacked on to the shell prompt?

Then that's because you don't wait for all your child processes, only the last one. And there's no guarantee that the child-processes will execute in any specific order.

That means your parent process could exit before all child-processes have finished, which means that the shell is back in control and will display the prompt.

You should really wait for *all* child-processes. Preferably in a second loop if you want the child-processes to run in parallel.

Comment: if I waited on all of them, wouldn't it just wait until that child is done then move onto the next one? that would just seem like a normal loop instead of running them all in parallel.

Comment: @MarchingDelta That's why I recommended that you do the waiting in a separate loop, after you forked all child processes.

Comment: that worked. but if the parent exited before the child processes were done, wouldn't they just become orphans and have a ppid of 1?

Comment: @MarchingDelta Yes, but it's bad behavior. And besides, as you seen with your program could have other consequences outside of your program.